Slow initialization of threads in C# application
There is an WPF-application that works with hundreds of devices connecting via a socket. To ensure the independence of entities from each other, connections of each of them occur in a separate thread, called through Task.Run(Connect). Connect() initializes the socket and waits for a connection. In fact, I see that when the application starts, 24 threads are initialized at once, and the rest are added approximately once per second.
If you look at the VS, in debugging you can see that the threads have been created and are in the “scheduled” status.

My guesses.
This may be due to the fact that the computer has 24 cores and the initial initialization scatters threads across the cores, so they start at the same time. And then some thread manager starts working, waiting for resources to be released and only then initializing the next thread. But this is strange, since a second is a very long time. In addition, if you then reconnect all several hundred devices at once, they return almost instantly. That is, it is the initialization of threads that occurs slowly, and their further work is carried out without visible delays.
Is it possible to speed up the connection initialization process?
I tried putting stubs with a wait timer instead of a connection in the Connect() function to eliminate the possible influence of Socket initialization. But this does not affect the initialization of threads in any way.
Simple reproducible example.
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    Task.Run(Connect);
}

Console.ReadKey();

static void Connect()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Thread {System.Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId} started");
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
}


See ThreadPool.SetMinThreads - increase the value. Or use TaskFactory.StartNew method with TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning parameter.

However, show us your code with Socket. You must use async methods instead of creating Tasks/Threads.

Your mistake is trying to put them all on different threads. You shouldn't use Threads, instead use async to prevent blocking while waiting for responses.

@AlexanderPetrov This is almost certainly an XY problem, increasing the threadpool is not the correct answer.

Threads are expensive and slow to create. But Tasks aren't threads. They may use them, but they are not the same.

Thread per connection is well known not to scale well.

Thank you for your answers. "ThreadPool.SetMinThreads" - looks like a temporary solution. I agree that the thread per each connection is quite expensive and not scalable. Therefore, I will look for alternative solutions.
